# Node JS Imap-simple disconnect error after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, imap

I fetch unread messages in a middle ware that triggers my function every five minutes. It is successfully completing the request but eventually It triggers and crashes my nodejs process. With an error of:

Error: This socket has been ended by the other party

I have tried adding all these catches and error handling but It seams it eventually times out my connection to my inbox? Am I not reconnecting on every request to access my inbox?

Here is my code (also I have tried with authTimeout: 3000 in the config before anyone suggests that is the issue):

```
imap: {
    user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    password: 'myPW',
    host: 'imap.gmail.com',
    port: 993,
    tls: true,
    keepalive: true
}

 imaps.connect(settings.emailConfig).then(function (connection) {
    return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
        var searchCriteria = ['UNSEEN'];//only grab unread messages in LTS email
        var fetchOptions = {
            bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT', ''],
            markSeen: true//mark as read
        };
        return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(function (messages) {
            console.log('looking for unread messages')
            if (messages.length > 0) {
                console.log('unread messages to save')
                console.log('looking at messages : ' + util.inspect(messages, { depth: null }))
                var saveUnreadEmais = messages.map(function (item) {//resolve each promise of unread message
                    var all = _.find(item.parts, { "which": "" })
                    var id = item.attributes.uid;
                    var idHeader = "Imap-Id: " + id + "\r\n";
                    simpleParser(idHeader + all.body, (err, mail) => {

                        var BarCode = "";
                        var subject = mail.subject;
                        var to = mail.to.value[0].address;
                        var from = mail.from.value[0].address;
                        var text = mail.text;

                        if (mail.subject.includes('Barcode :')) {//if the message to the system includes BarCode in the subject line grab it
                            var split = mail.subject.split(':');
                            BarCode = split[1];
                        }
                        if (!subject) {
                            subject = "LTS Email Recieved - Barcode : " + BarCode;
                        }
                        if (!text) {
                            text = "LTS auto email"
                        }
                        var newrec = {};
                        newrec.MessageDate = new Date();
                        newrec.MessageFor = to;
                        newrec.MessageFrom = from;
                        newrec.Message = text;
                        newrec.MessageAbout = BarCode;
                        newrec.MessageSubject = subject;
                        newrec.MessageStatusCode = 1;//1 sent, 2 read, 3 saved, -1 deleted
                        //console.log('saving message with details of : ' + util.inspect(newrec, { depth: null }))
                        return db.knex('dbo.PersonnelMessages').insert(newrec).then((data) => {
                            return "sent";
                        });
                    });
                });
                return Promise.all(saveUnreadEmais).then(() => {
                    //do anything you want after saving all unred emails to our db. 
                }).catch((err) => { console.log("error : " + err) })
            }
            else {
                console.log('no new emails')
            }
        }).catch((err) => { console.log("error : " + err) })
    }).catch((err) => { console.log("opening inbox error : " + err) })
}).then(function () {
    console.log('In the INBOX');
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log('error : ' + e);
});
```

Comment: bare in mind this is all in a scheduled timer middleware function

Comment: try this https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap/issues/561